# jQuery Get value of previous characters up till certain character within textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, textarea

I making a text editor using jquery and electron. I would like to be able to make the text editor autocomplete HTML tags.

What I would like is when the user types a tag, for example `<tag>` a closing `</tag>` is than inserted. I am planning to do this by detecting when `>` is typed and saving the characters up until `<` as a variable. I would then insert those characters between `</` and `>`. However I am unsure how to do this.

I have the following code:

```
function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elemId);
    el.value = el.value;
    if (el !== null) {
        if (el.createTextRange) {
            var range = el.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
            return true;
        } else {
            if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart === 0) {
                el.focus();
                el.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
                return true;
            } else {
                el.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

$("#input").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === ">") {
        $("#input").focus();
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', true, '></>');
        var cursorPosition = $('#input').prop("selectionStart");
        setCaretPosition('input', cursorPosition - 3);

    }
});
```

and

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="input" spellcheck="false" wrap="off" placeholder="Get Creative!"></textarea>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You can replace the value of the textarea with: substring from the first position of the `textarea`'s value to the position the closing `>` for the opening tag **added with** the closing tag string **and** the remaining string like below. Then, set the cursor position using `setSelectionRange` (read further [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)). Also, you can get the caret position of a `textarea` using `textarea.selectionStart`. It is supported in most browsers (look [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=selectionStart) to find out which browser supports this property).

Here's a very basic automatic closing tag insertion (try inserting "Test Text", go to the beginning of the textarea, then add a tag):

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea')
let tag = {
  opened: false,
  textStart: null,
  textEnd: null
}

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === '<') {
    tag.opened = true
    tag.textStart = textarea.selectionStart + 1
  } else if (e.key === '>') {
    e.preventDefault()
    tag.textEnd = textarea.selectionStart
    const tagText = textarea.value.substring(tag.textStart, tag.textEnd)
    const closingTag = `</${tagText}>`
    const value = textarea.value
    const beforeClosingTagText = value.substring(0, textarea.selectionStart)
    const afterClosingTagText = value.substring(textarea.selectionStart)
    const endCaretPosition = beforeClosingTagText.length + 1

    textarea.value = `${beforeClosingTagText}>${closingTag}${afterClosingTagText}`
    textarea.setSelectionRange(endCaretPosition, endCaretPosition)
    tag = {
      opened: false,
      textStart: null,
      textEnd: null
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #12121244;
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #8fdef7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" spellcheck="false" wrap="off" placeholder="Get Creative!"></textarea>
```

Note that the above code only answers your question of *getting values from a certain position to another certain position in a textarea* and inserting said value as a closing tag; it does not deal with other scenarios that are crucial in text editors. Some scenarios that you still need to handle yourself that come to mind include:

- What if a person wants to insert a lesser than sign and not a tag (e.g. `3 < 4`)?
- What if a person decides to delete the opening of the opening tag?
- What if a person moves the caret position after opening a tag and uses a greater than sign `>` elsewhere before closing said tag?

Furthermore, `execCommand` is obsolete and [its use is discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see what you mean about this method not being ideal for text editors. Can you perhaps point me in the direction of a more suitable solution for a text area, or possibly put another solution in your answer?

Comment: @AlexHawking I'm not saying that this is not a suitable solution. It is. However, you just have to consider all those scenarios and others that may occur. Do you know VS Code? It also has an auto close tag feature (see here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag). You can access their code here: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-auto-close-tag/blob/master/src/extension.ts and see what they did to make their auto close tag feature.

Comment: Ok cool, I'm thinking of making a function that checks if the document is HTML and only apply the autcomplete if it is. This is how I will start for now and eventually add code to check if the user is typing between two script tags.

Comment: @AlexHawking Apologies. The Github repo I linked does not contain code from VS directly. It's someone else that created an emulation of what VSCode and Sublime Text do to auto close tags in XML, JS, etc.

Comment: @AlexHawking Great! Have you considered giving the bounty away?